# $timeout if and else condition not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular and javascript.

I am using a timeout function to do some task.

Here I have used an if and else condition in the timeout.

I am Highlighting the whole url if it contains the word.

Here the code is not working if the conditions are true or false. It's like it is not going in the if condition of `checkurls`. After completion of for each it goes in the if condition?

Is there any thing wrong with my code ?

```js
if (uploadService.getOrphans()) {
  angular.forEach(uploadService.getOrphans(), function(orphan) {
        var text = orphan.attributes.text;
        if (first_iteration) {
          $timeout(function() {
            console.log($('div#htmlEditor').text());
            var check = $('div#htmlEditor').find("a[href*=" + text + "]");
            if (check.length > 0) {
              $('div#htmlEditor').find("a[href*=" + text + "]").addClass('mark');
              checkurls = true;
            }
          }, 0);
          if (!checkurls) {
            console.log("in the if of checkurl");
            responseData = $scope.highlightHTML(responseData, orphan.attributes.text, false);
          }
          first_iteration = false;
        } else {
          var checkURLContain = false;
          //$(document).ready(function() {  
          $timeout(function() {
            console.log($('div#htmlEditor').text());
            var isvaluepreseninurl = $('div#htmlEditor').find("a[href*=" + text + "]");
            //console.log(isvaluepreseninurl);
            if (isvaluepreseninurl.length > 0) {
              console.log("in timeout");
              $('div#htmlEditor').find("a[href*=" + text + "]").addClass('mark');
              checkURLContain = true;
              console.log("value of checkurls  -->", checkURLContain);
            }
          }, 0);
          //});
          console.log("value of checkurls  -->", checkURLContain);
          if (!checkurls) {
            var check = $scope.isAlreadyHighlightedOrphan(responseData, orphan.attributes.text);
            if (!check) {
              responseData = $scope.highlightHTML(responseData, orphan.attributes.text, false);
            }
          }
        }
        //}
```

Comment: Your code is not valid.

Comment: You need to debug your code to see which line throw the error. you can debug your js file using Chrome :  inspect element -> Slource , then select your file which contain this code and put a breakpoint inside the foreach, and use F10 to debug. Also make sure you define  $timeout as a dependency on your controller.

Comment: You're combining jQuery and AngularJS. If you use jQuery to maniuplate DOM, angular doesn't know about that and nothing happens. Go with either Angular or jQuery, don't combine them like you are right now.

Comment: How can I use if else condition in timeout function ?